# SQL Server : how to make multiple references to the same table substituting values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a few SQL Server tables that build the structuring of a phrase or task..

Table 1 has about 5 or 6 columns all containing integers that correspond to a different table.

Table 1 Example: 123,32,9999,0,213,321.

The first column is like a where condition that links to table 2 (holds index number and corresponding condition text to replace like, 'Where', 'After'). then the second column links to the phrase/object table which contains words for example like, 'Pay' or 'cashier'. And so on.

I can run a select statement that left joins the master, 1st table full of indexes to the other tables but my issue is when 3 columns in the first table all reference that second table that contains the mass of phrase/object words.

What is a function to best substitute the integers from a Select Statement of Table 1 that makes numerous references to another table ?

A Desired Returned result could be : After(Table 2 ref.) dinner(Table 3 Ref) children (Table3 Ref) wash (Table 3 Ref) all (Table 4 Ref) dishes (Table 3 Ref)

I understand this may not be an ideal structure of tables but I am helping a friend.
Thank you.

PS we are both beginners as you may tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your situation where you have multiple columns referencing back to the same table you can JOIN the same table again and just alias it differently .. something like ....

```
SELECT R1.SomeColumn, R2.SomeColumn
FROM Master_table M 
         INNER JOIN Refrenced_Table R1  --<-- Alias R1
ON M.Column1 = R1.Pk                   -- JOIN Condition with Alias R1
       INNER JOIN Refrenced_Table R2      --<-- Alias R2
ON M.Column2 = R2.Pk                  -- JOin condition with Alias R2
```

Join the Master table back to Referencing table as many as column you have which references back to that table each time with a different Alias.

In you Select Statement use Columns comming from Different aliases to get the required results.

Comment: Not quite Sure I understand.. I don't get how do I make different references to that single text table from the phrase table. the Master_Table has 3 different columns.. All integers that connect in the same exact way.

Comment: It would be more like Select r1.text1, r1.text2 from MasterTab M Inner Join ReferencedTable r1 on (r1.index = M.someIndex1) Inner Join ReferecedTable r1 on (r1.Index = M.SomeIndex2)

Comment: I misunderstood your answer at first. makes sense and works now